# ActionBar OverflowMenu item disappears on click

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` with overflow menu items. Each item's `onClick` starts an `Activity` using an `Intent`. In some devices, the item text disappears and the menu remains stuck until the activity opens.

I think that it waits for the `Activity` to open. Is there anyway to force the overflow menu to close immediately instead of seeing the menu with an empty text entry?

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari: I am not sure the link has anything to do with the question. The link is about forcing the OverFlowMenu while this question is about the OverFlowMenu staying open till an Activity opens.

Comment: @SiddharthLele : I thought it might be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error, what solved this for me is really simple: close the menu :)

```
  @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        closeOptionsMenu();

        .....
        .....        
        .....
        return .....;
    }
```