# force a soft menu to appear for all android ddevices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, optionmenu

I'm using ActionBarSherloc and for the phones that have a physical menu the dots soft menu icon is not shown this is the scenario for phones like the s3 but I need to get the behavior of the Samsung Nexus and always have menu on the top right corner of the screen. 
This is the code I use:

```
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
```

But on S3 I don't have the menu show on the screen and I need to press the physical menu button to open the option menu, this behavior might be confusing for users.
Also I have tried something like

```
<menu>
 <item id=item_1 icon="the actual soft menu icon" android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
     <item/>
     <item/>
     <item/>
    </menu>
 <item>
 <item  id=item_2 icon = "other menu item" android:showAsAction="always">       
</menu>
```

but on this design it seems that the the two icon items are always shown and the   `showAsAcrion` parameter is not considered. I relay need to be able to show and hide the item `item_1` depending on the size of the ActionBar.
Thanks

Comment: There is a theme setting to force the menu button to show in ActionbarSherlock but it doesn't always work and has been depricated.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634685/display-action-bar-menu-button/14634780#comment20443693_14634780

I described a workaround, maybe it will be good for you.