# overflow menu in actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an app both android smartphone and tablet. 
I'm trying to add the menu button on the actionbar on android tablet (3.x and greater). 
I read some other questions on stackoverflow (like that: [How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button) ) but it is not what i want to.

at the moment I'm using the title bar to show the menu button, as you can see in this screen:
[image]

And it's a "good" solution but only for version 3.x, because the version 4.x are both for smartphone and tablet, and i don't want to see the title bar because of esthetic reasons.
so I would like to have something like that
[image]

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, except by specifying an `android:targetSdkVersion` of 10 or less, which at this point in time is not a good idea, as it will make your app look old.

If you do not wish to use an action bar, that is fine, but then you need to create your own menus that are designed to go with your own UI.

Comment: mmm you are right, and i think it's a best solution...
my app needs work on sdk version 10 and greater. so what do i do? i use a version check to not show the actionbar? thank you for your time CommonsWare

Comment: @antedesk: If you "don't want to see the title bar because of esthetic reasons", you do not need to do a version check for that. Simply suppress the action bar, probably via a `NoActionBar` theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`). For supporting this on API Level 10 and up, you will probably need to define your own custom theme that inherits from something like `Theme.NoTitleBar` on older devices and from something like `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` on newer devices (using `res/values-v11/` for the latter resource).