# How to use Overflow menu in TabActivity?

Tags: android, menu

I want to use overflow menu for device which not have menu button(hardware).
I use overflow menu in simple Activity project it work fine. But in tabActivity overflow menu not visible at top corner(three dot).

How to use overflow menu in tabActivity?
I am also use,

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

And
I refer **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492791/how-do-i-show-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android)** 
It work fine, but not in TabActivity.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry for bad English

Comment: You want it in the action bar?

Comment: It should not be a problem to use it in your TabActivity, try setting your showAsAction to ifRoom. Like: android:showAsAction="ifRoom"