# Android options menu not showing in action bar version 4.1

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating a very simple action bar. I have just added 2 items in the menu but still it does not work for Android 4.1. It does work on nexus 5 emulator though.

`menu_main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_exit"
        android:title="Exit"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

---

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.mycompany.actionbaractivitypractise;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 } 


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is  present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Any comments or suggestions will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Newer phones, with no hardware menu button automatically add an Overflow menu icon to the Action Bar. but in your case The phones which have menu hardware button show extra menu items on click of the hardware button.

Comment: Can Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15493649/1761003

Comment: You should try adding `android:orderInCategory` attribute in menu items

Answer (score -2):

Your java code is correct but in menu_menu.xml instead of app: use android it will work : 
Example:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_exit"
    android:title="Exit"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: `Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` error message by Android Studio