# ActionBarSherlock menu item showing up on tablet not on phone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock to create a menu (with the three dots) at the top and then have a few items as a submenu. The menu is showing up on tablets, but not on a four inch phone. The app can run on sdkVersion 9-17.

My menu.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_weather"
        android:title="@string/weather"
        android:icon="@drawable/weather_tab"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_emergency"
        android:title="@string/emergency_nums" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_suggest"
        android:title="@string/friend"  />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_support"
        android:title="@string/faq" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:title="@string/about" />

</menu>
```

And I have a menu inflate of:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If the device has an option button then actionbarsherlock wont show the three dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching and this is what finally worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/2291915

I hope this can help someone else. I hadn't realized because I was using this on an emulator it was really about whether there was hard or soft buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In your res/menu/menu.xml, your item can have a `android:showAsAction` parameter, which defines when to show them. You can then set a bunch of parameters that will help you displaying them (or not) more easily on phones and tablets. If you want to always show the menu item, just set this parameter to "always".

More here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: If I set the showAsAction to always, or if room it displays the text of the menu items, which I don't want. I want it to show the three dots and when this is clicked a submenu appears with these items in there.

Comment: Don't set a title to the ones you set as always

Comment: I might just not be understanding, but I set the showAsAction="always" and removed the title. This displayed the icon, but still not showing the three dots.

Comment: If you want your items in the 3-dots menu, then showAsAction should be set to never, because you never want them to show in the ActionBar (and therefore you need a title for those). For the ones you don't want in the 3-dot menu, you can either set them to always or ifRoom. Take the time to understand what all of those params do from the link above, it's worth understanding it well

Comment: One thing that you might not be taking into consideration is that phones with a menu button don't display the 3-dots menu, instead, those options are accessible when pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```