# Change the selected item highlight colour for the hard-menu-key menu

Tags: android, android-theme

I've used the [action bar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to generate a custom action bar theme for an app, and it works well after a few tweaks. My custom theme is based on Holo (the dark version) and changes the highlight colours. My action bar overflow menu correctly shows my custom `state_pressed` colour on the overflow items when I press them. I've set `android:colorPressedHighlight` to the colour I want, and put an appropriate drawable for `android:selectableItemBackground`.

The problem is on one of my test devices, which has a hard menu button. (It's a Samsung Galaxy S III.) When I show the overflow menu with the hard menu button, pressing an item from this menu gives it the default blue highlight. Either it uses another attr instead of `android:selectableItemBackground`, or it's taking it from another style. I'd like to know what attr it's using, or what style it's taking it from, so that I can set this colour.

P.S. Before anyone suggests it, I know that you can use `android:panelBackground` to set the background of the bottom menu. But I don't want to change the overall menu background, only the item background.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I've had a look through the platform resources and it seems the `panelMenuListTheme` attribute is a likely candidate, but unfortunately both it and the `Theme.Holo.CompactMenu` that it refers to are not publicly accessible.  I'm considering this hack (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/5171) to force use of the overflow menu as an alternative.

Comment: No, I still don't have a solution.

Comment: Is still a mystery how to accomplish that? I'm stuck on this customization

Comment: @DanHulme How did you make the overflow menu work? I used ActionBar Style Generator too, but it only creates a background 9 patch drawable. Pressed background states are not changed. Care to specify it better? You could edit the question or post here in the comments the menu style used. It would really help.

Comment: @domenicop There's already a question about that on this site. If it doesn't help, ask a new question and I'll come and look at it for you.