# How to remove menu hardware key from your android app

Tags: android-intent, android-actionbar

i was searching around and I can't find solution for my problem. I want to remove menu hardware key from my app, so I can get my menu overflow in the action bar

Here is my code:

```
package gridview;

import fragments.MainFragment;
import gab.GlassActionBarHelper;
import hd.light.AboutDev;
import hd.light.R;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private GlassActionBarHelper helper;

    // Starts the Activity for the gridview
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.theme_name), 0);
        checkBuild();

        helper = new GlassActionBarHelper().contentLayout(R.layout.gridview_main);
        setContentView(helper.createView(this));

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
        .commit();
    }

    public void checkBuild() {
      int buildNum = prefs.getInt("Build Number", 1);
      int currentVersion = 0;

      try {
        currentVersion = getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
      }
      catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
        if(currentVersion > buildNum) {
              getChangelog().show();
              Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putInt("Build Number", currentVersion);
              editor.commit();
            }
      }

    public Dialog getChangelog()
     {
        final Dialog CDialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
        CDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.changelog_title));
        CDialog.setContentView(R.layout.changelog);
        CDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        CDialog.setCancelable(true);

        Button Close = (Button) CDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        Close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
         CDialog.dismiss();
         }
        });

        return CDialog;
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.shareButton:
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.app_link));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));
                break;
            case R.id.rateButton:
                Intent rate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse
                        ("market://details?id=your.icons.name.here"));
                startActivity(rate);
                break;
            case R.id.emailButton:
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "the1dynasty.android@gmail.com" });
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getText(R.string.email_subject));
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Contact Developer"));

                break;
            case R.id.aboutButton:
                Intent about = new Intent(Main.this, AboutDev.class);
                startActivity(about);
                break;
            case R.id.donateButton:
                Intent donate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse
                        ("http://bit.ly/YWwhWu"));
                startActivity(donate);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Since I own Galaxy S4 and when i press menu button, I got popup from the bottom. When I test this on Nexus 4 emulator, which do not own menu button, I got desired result, menu overflow (3 dots) in the action bar. How can I remove menu hardware key from my app? Also, i followed instructions from here ---> [How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button) but I got some errors.

Can some please add this to my code and post whole code here, so I can see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this question:

[How to force use of overflow menu on devices with menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button)

To disable hardware menu key you can use this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
            return true;
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) 
    {           
        return false;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: Ill try as soon as I come home. Let you know. Thanks so much

Comment: no it doestn work, i got FC when add your code into mine. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It will not work mate, since I am using ActionBarSherlock. I have to remove it first, then I will try

Comment: I'm working right now and I haven't got free time... If you can remove ActionBarSherlock I'm sure that this code works.

Comment: Yes, but it takes time to remove all ABS :(