# Action bar overflow menu items doesn't appear

Tags: android

I've just finished a test app that I wanted to be supported in all android devices from 2.1, so I used the support library to the support the action bar but I'm getting a problem in a device with android 2.3 ... Everything seems to be fine, the action bar and all the itens I choosed to be show "ifRoom" are appearing but the overflow drop down itens menu is missing, I don't really know why. Does android devices below 3.0 support this overflow menu or what?

There's my xml code in the second activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:teste="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    teste:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_edit"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    teste:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    android:title="@string/action_edit" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    teste:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings" />
```

Anyone can help me pls? 
ps: sorry the bad English

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9287015/826657

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overflow menu is hidden in ActionBar if your device has hardware 'Menu' button.
Press it and check - your items should be there :)

Comment: Was caught by this too, not once :)

Comment: how can I make the menu to appear always, despite having a hardware menu button?

Comment: @Sartheris there are some hacks... see answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button