# Settings is coming in Overflow with Action Bar Support Library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am developing an action bar with Support Library v3 appcompat. Settings option is not coming in overflow. Rather I need to press menu from my mobile and then settings is coming....

Below is the code:
main_activity_actions.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Configuration:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Search Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea why this is behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Actionbar` overflow buttons won't show on the devices have the hardware menu button, as this is prevented by design,

From the Compatibility in Design documents [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html)

> Android phones with traditional navigation hardware keys don't display
>   the virtual navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. Instead, the
>   action overflow is available from the menu hardware key.

You can try a hack although to forcibly show the overflow menu, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/826657)

Comment: you are welcome, I have experienced the same thing when I started. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Settings option is not coming in overflow. Rather I need to press menu from my mobile and then settings is coming

That *is* the overflow. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems):

> Actions that can't fit in the action bar or aren't important enough are hidden in the action overflow. The user can reveal a list of the other actions by pressing the overflow button on the right side (or the device Menu button, if available).