# Action overflow menu shows up always regardless of having phone hardware button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-actionmode

[image]

ActionBar overflow menu should always Visible.

ActionBar overflow menu should always Visible in the all Device regardless of having hardware menu or not.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `android:showAsAction` attribute in each item.

If you would want to show it always visible then include **`android:showAsAction="always"`** and if you don't then include **`android:showAsAction="never"`**