# is Disabling Menu Button possible?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am trying to make a restricted android launcher for some people. 
The key features that I am trying is

- Giving Access to Selected App to be laucnched.
- Disable the button that allows to show user to show every app installed on the phone
- Disable physical button (menu) in order to restrict user to go in to "Settings" menu of Android.

If these features are possible, it would be great if you could link me any examples or explain how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

Documentation says:

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false
>   it will not be shown.

Comment: This disables all things menu related. I want the overflow menu button in the action bar, but just want to disable the hardware menu button.

Comment: @user2968401 For that I guess, you will need to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button

Answer (score 3):

Override the onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: If possible, it would be helpful that you could explain what this code does.. since I am not used to android coding.. thx..

Answer (score 1):

Check the [**AndroidDoc**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Implement the keylistener and Override the onKeyDown method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean clickedPhysicalMenu = false;
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        clickedPhysicalMenu = true;
    }
    return clickedPhysicalMenu;
}
```

Comment: If possible, it would be helpful that you could explain what this code does.. since I am not used to android coding.. thx

Comment: This is incorrect to disable the menu key you should return true to prevent further propagation of the event  see [link]https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)[link]
`@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
         return true;
     }

     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }`