# Android ActionBar Compat Overlow menu with sub-menu

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

In my application, I am using sub-menus to group some elements together (see XML below). It works fine on devices without a hardware menu button, but I am having issues with devices with an hardware button.

When it works, I can click on "Sort" in the menu, and it display a new menu in place of the first one with the corresponding option.

When it does not, a dialog opens with the sub-menu options. This dialog has a light theme with white texts, so it is unusable. Is there a way to make it behave the same way as on device without a hardware menu button? Or at least have a correctly styled dialog?

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245, but it feels like a hack, and does not seem to work for all devices.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/sort"
        app:showAsAction="never">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/menu_sort"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_sort_a"
                    android:title="@string/sort_a"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_sort_b"
                    android:title="@string/sort_b"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_sort_c"
                    android:title="@string/sort_c"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_sort_d"
                    android:title="@string/sort_d"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160290) for this. Let's pray for it to be resolved soon.

Comment: this answer should be a comment to the question. it is not constructive and does not help solving the question

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look for update from Google on this issue.

Comment: Hey, they fixed it! v. 22.2.0