# Overflow Menu shows on layout but not on emulator

Tags: android

as the title says my overflow menu is being displayed on the layout however when I run it on an emulator it does not show up...
I wonder what's the problem, please help.

Comment: What is the API of of the emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your emulator is also emulating the menu hardware button ? you should get a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button)