# How to enforce action bar settings icon at old android APIs

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, settings

The new android smartphones have no menu settings button. Instead, the settings icon is in the ActionBar.

If I run my app on an old smartphone, there is no settings icon in the actionbar. You have to click at the menu settings button of the smartphone.

How can I enforce at older smartphones (APIs) that the settings icon is also in the ActionBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is actually **intended** by design as per the [Backwards compatibility section](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html) of the Android Design Guide.

> Android phones with traditional navigation hardware keys don't display
>   the virtual navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. Instead, the
>   action overflow is available from the menu hardware key

A quote from a previous answer explains why you shouldn't be concerned with this behaviour:

> Ultimately it's
>   more important to the user experience that your app behave
>   *consistently with every other app* on the same device, than that it
>   behave consistently with itself across all devices. - [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287015/717778)

However, if you are still adamant you wish to see the same UI across all devices you can consider the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
        android:icon="@drawable/overflow_image"
        android:orderInCategory="11111"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/settings_item"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/settings"/>
        </menu>
    </item>  
</menu>
```

This example would use a drawable resource `overflow_image`, as the 'three dots' and always show on the toolbar and behave as you require. You would just need to source the correct drawable

Comment: But now there is the word SETTINGS, but I want to have the 3 points with the dropdown menu. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean - I will edit my answer